# data.table not retaining key workaround

Tags: r, data.table

`data.table` does not retain key where doing a subset

```
setkey(DT,a,b,c)
key(DT[,list(a,b)]) # return NULL
```

Do anybody have a workaround this (where X Y hence Z are data.table) ?
I actually want to do this =>

```
Z = X[,list(a, b, c)][Y, mult='last']
```

NOTE: I could do

```
X2 = X[,list(a, b, c)]
setattr(X2,"sorted",c("a","b","c"))
Z = X2[Y, mult='last']
```

but I do not want to copy X into X2

EDIT example:

```
Y = data.table(a=seq(2,4),key="a")
X = data.table(a=seq(1,5),b=seq(2,6),c=sample(letters,5),key="a,b,c")
X[,list(a, b, c)][Y, mult='last']
Error in `[.data.table`(X[, list(a, b, c)], Y, mult = "last") : 
When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed
```

---

**UPDATE (eddi):** As of [version 1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&revision=999&root=datatable) this has been fixed and the key is retained in the first subset, so that the result is:

```
X[,list(a, b, c)][Y, mult='last']
#   a b c
#1: 2 3 k
#2: 3 4 z
#3: 4 5 u
```

Comment: Please provide an example to work with.

Comment: Well, I find it easier to work with the data. And I don't want to create one every time one comes up with a question (however simple it might be). I'll leave to someone else to answer.

Comment: @eddi: Nice! I had been doing this operation the `with=FALSE` way you mentioned below. Your update is a little cryptic insomuch as it requires reading the whole post; the result of `key(DT[,list(a,b)])` would be clearer. Also, is a copy made (another of the OP's concerns)? I'd be surprised if it was possible to avoid making a copy...

Comment: @Frank thanks, good suggestion, edited. The same amount of copying I think happens which is column a, b and c get copied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
setkey(X[,list(a, b, c)])[Y, mult='last']
```

Alternatively, you can do X[Y] and then set all other columns from X to NULL

```
X[Y, mult="last"][, c(names_to_remove) := NULL]
```

Comment: Being punished for my lazyness... time for coffee... I am tempted to downvote my own question, good I can't do it

Comment: Arun, @statquant, Not sure what's happened here. Have reopened an old feature request that I thought was implemented, and changed it to bug status. [#295 Retain key after order-preserving subset](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=295&group_id=240&atid=975)

Comment: @MatthewDowle, I do not remember having seen this feature implemented, and I tend to look at the "What's new" when you release...

Comment: It was in NEWS for 1.8.1: "Ordered subsets now retain x's key. Always for logical and keyed i, using base::is.unsorted() for integer and unkeyed i. Implements FR#295."   It seems I did the fancy stuff and forgot the basic case when `i` is missing.

Comment: another alternative is: `X[, c('a', 'b', 'c'), with = FALSE][Y, mult='last']`